# IBM Watson - Conversation API integration returns Resource Not Found error (404)

Tags: watson-conversation, watson

I am trying to integrate watson from salesforce (Http Callout) and received 404 error. Then I tried the sameusing Postman tool but getting the same result

Added conversation credentials in request header

**Request Endpoint**

https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api/v1/workspaces/883c7704-02c4-41fc-b8a0-aea1d0325c5a/message?version=2016-09-20

**Request Body**

```
{
  "application/json": {
    "input": {
      "text": "Hi"
    },       
    "alternate_intents": true
  }
}
```

**Response Body**

```
{
  "error": "Resource not found"
}
```

**Status**
`404 Not found`

Please let me know what is the issue here. I am not sure whether the way I added version and workspace id in the endpoint went wrong

Comment: Can you tell the specific error?The question is really not clear

Comment: Have you put credentials identifying your provisioned conversation instance on bluemix into the request header?

Comment: Yes I added credentials in header

Comment: @AthifShaffy, updated my post

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I found that it's simply rate limiting that kicks in.

According to the docs [here](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/?curl#send_message) there is no limit for the endpoint, however that turns out to be untrue. If you send a few thousand messages in quick succession, you'll start getting 404 Not Found until the quota resets, which seems to take around 1 hour.

Answer (score 1):

The request body doesn't seem right. It should be JSON with e.g. this structure (see api ref. page in watson conversation service doc.):

```
{
  "input": {
    "text": "Hi"
  }
}
```

`application/json` should be the content type. Sample request with `curl`:

```
curl -X POST -u "{username}":"{password}" -H "Content-Type:application/json" --data "{\"input\": {\"text\": \"Hi\"}}" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api/v1/workspaces/<workspace_id>/message?version=2017-02-10"
```

See the API Reference for more details: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/

Comment: I tried this input but the error is same. I believe something wrong with my endpoint or parameters

Comment: Also, you can try to use conversation-simple app sample available on git hub, link in the doc.